# Difference between CZML.process and CZML.load

Tags: cesiumjs, czml

Can someone tell me what are the performance and differences between these two functions (`CZML.load` and `CZML.process`) when calling CZML data sources on our cesium files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/CzmlDataSource.html#load), `load` will clear out existing data from the dataSource prior to processing the incoming data.  `process` will not, so can be used to update existing entities, for example if realtime telemetry is being streamed in.

Comment: So if I need to load several data sources and actively working with the data of one of them, can I use process? Should I load a data source at first and then call process. I wish there was an example of process application.

Comment: No, if you have multiple separate dataSources, you should create a new CzmlDataSource for each one and call `load` on it.  Cesium viewer keeps a list of multiple dataSources and will display all objects from all of them.  `process` is typically not used in user apps unless the server sends new information about an existing entity in an existing dataSource.  Can you clarify what you mean "actively working with the data" in one dataSource?  What type of work?

Comment: I want to have access to data loaded from CZML When I finish loading it and outside of the load function. For example I want to fill out an array object  when I am loading CZML file and be able to use that array outside of the load function. I thought maybe I can use process. but It seems I'm wrong, I can ask it as separate question with example code if you think that's better.

Comment: Yep, let's make that a separate question.  Thanks.